# Java (toString and Constructors)

Tags: java

Hi I am having difficulty with one of my programming projects(I am not asking for code, I'm just having problem with the logic of the program). The assignment is to create a program where you take in a String representation of an int eg: "1363", convert it to an int, hold it in an array or array list do basic operations like adding , subtraction, multiplication, etc... then rewrite the result using the toString method in string format. well, i'm having problem just getting the toString method to work properly. for example when i do input checking i create two objects of the class because essentially there is supposed to be two big int numbers and the result comes out wrong and i can't figure out why. for example, i stop the program whenever you have letters in the string instead of numbers which is right but that only works if the first object has a letter, if the second object has a letter it doesn't even print out the result for the first object but writes out the error message for the second object. i don't know how to do it in a way where it does the error checking for the first object and then it proceeds with the error checking for the second object instead of messing up the program if the second object has an error. here is my code so far and my professor gave us a main class for us to test our toString method and i will post both up, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BigInt {


    //private static final String String = null;

    private ArrayList <Integer> integerArray; // only need one array
    // have to fix the toString and constructors

    private char sign;


    //private Object bigNum;

    //public final int bigNum; 


    public BigInt(char sign)

    {
        //this.bigNum = bigNum;
        this.sign = sign;
        //this.sign = '+';

        this.integerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }

    public BigInt (String input) 

    {

        setSign(input);

        setInt(input);

        //addTwoBigNum(input);

    }
    public char getSign () 
    {
        return sign;
    }

    public void setSign (String input)

    {

        if (input.charAt(0) == '+' || input.charAt(0) == '1' || input.charAt(0) == '2'

                || input.charAt(0) == '3' || input.charAt(0) == '4' || input.charAt(0) == '5'

                || input.charAt(0) == '6' || input.charAt(0) == '7' || input.charAt(0) == '8'

                || input.charAt(0) == '9' || input.charAt(0) == '0')

        {

            this.sign ='+';

        }

        else if (input.charAt(0) == '-')

        {

            this.sign ='-';

        }

        else 

        {

            System.out.println("Invalid sign");

        }

    }

    public void setInt (String input)

    {

        this.integerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i= input.length() -1; i>=0; i--)

        {

            if (input.charAt(0) == '1' || input.charAt(0) == '2' || input.charAt(0) == '3'

                    || input.charAt(0) == '4' || input.charAt(0) == '4' || input.charAt(0) == '6'

                    || input.charAt(0) == '7' || input.charAt(0) == '7' || input.charAt(0) == '9'

                    || input.charAt(0) == '0')

            {

                integerArray.add(new Integer(input.charAt(i) -48));

            }

            else if (input.charAt(i) == '+' || input.charAt(i) == '-' && i== 0)

            {

                break;

            }

            else if (input.charAt(i) == '+' || input.charAt(i) == '-' && input.length() ==1)

            {

                System.out.println("Input must contain ar least one digit");

            }

            else 

            {

                System.out.println ("This is an invalid character in the string");

                integerArray.clear();
                System.exit(0);

                break;

            }

        }

    }

    @Override 

    public String toString()

    {

        String output = "";

        if (this.sign =='-' && this.integerArray.size() > 0 )

        {

            output = "-";

        }

        for (int i = this.integerArray.size() -1; i>=0 ; i--)

        {

            output = output + integerArray.get(i);

        }

        if(this.integerArray.size() == 0 )

        {

            output = "no integer";

        }

        return output;
    }
}





public class BigIntDemo {
    public static void main (String args [] ) {
        BigInt B1 = new BigInt("1234");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("1234asd");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("-1234");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("-1");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("1");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("0");
        // BigInt B1 = new BigInt("-0");
        //BigInt B1 = new BigInt("12222222222222233333333333333344444434");
        //BigInt B2 = new BigInt("4567");
        BigInt B2 = new BigInt("-45");
        //  BigInt B3 = new BigInt( );
        //   BigInt B4 = new BigInt( );
        System.out.println("explicit BigInt value is " + B1);
        System.out.println("default BigInt value is " + B2);
        //System.out.println("The sum of the two big ints is " + B1.add(B2));
        //System.out.println("please enter a new big integer value. ");
        //note that the code for readBigInt is almost identical to constructor 
        //B1.readBigInt();
        System.out.print("new BigInt value is " + B1);
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people keep down voting my post...

Comment: In your main method you never call toString()

Comment: @Rocketsm46 just a guess without reading the whole question: format your question. wall of text questions are hard to read. plus, it's too much code, try to get a snippet from the part, that is related to the question.

Comment: @Zhedar  I will remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
System.exit(0);
```

if this executes for the first object, your program will never reach the object after that.

Comment: copy, thanks for your feedback. i just have one question, even before i put the system.exit(0) in the code it would still not completely finish off checking the first object THEN moving on to the second object, what would i do in that situation that is pretty much what i need to know.